# how to safely remove an entity when not referenced anymore

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-mapping

I have the following Entity scenario:[image]

```
class PhyVarSelection
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *     targetEntity="PhyVar",
     *     cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="phy_var_sel",
     *     referencedColumnName="id",
     *     nullable=false)
     */
    protected $phyVar;

    ...
}


class PhyVar extends Variable
{
  //no inverse reference

}
```

`PhyVar`  could be referenced by multiple `PhyVarSelection`. When I delete a specific `PhyVarSelection`, I would like to delete the `PhyVar` if no other `PhyVarSelection` is referencing that `PhyVar` anymore.

`oncascade={"persist", "remove"}` on `PhyVarSelection` would try to remove it even though other selections are still referencing it. `oprhanRemoval=true` according to [this well written explanation](https://gist.github.com/pylebecq/f844d1f6860241d8b025) is not the right answer, but I could have misunderstood it.

Is a manual check the only way to accomplish this?